# How to create a record in sql with no data but a Primary Key

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example, I have an Order Table, this order table has the columns `OrderID` and `OrderDate`. At current the `OrderID` is an `Indentity(1,1)` and is auto generated.

I wish to create a record without giving a date for specific records. I have tried,

```
INSERT INTO Order() Values(), and similarly INSERT INTO Order();
```

I'm unsure if my syntax is anywhere near correct currently...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify `DEFAULT VALUES` to insert a row with defaults for all columns:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.[Order] DEFAULT VALUES;
```

The columns must either allow NULL values, have a default constraint, or have an auto-generated value. I suggest you avoid using reserved keywords like `ORDER` as identifiers (e.g. column and table names).

Answer (score 0):

If the second field is not marked as required, you can create a record with the following line:

```
INSERT INTO Order(OrderID) VALUES(NULL)
```